# Does exceptional bad -word- and exceptionally bad -word- mean the same?

Tags: meaning

If I wrote "exceptional bad service" and "exceptionally bad service", is this the same?

- If not what's the difference in meaning?
- Is it a clear mistake?

Comment: "Exceptional" is an adjective, and can't modify another adjective, so it modifies the noun instead.

Comment: _Exceptional_ on its own usually implies 'exceptionally good', so 'exceptional bad' sounds like a contradiction in terms.

Comment: "Exceptional bad service" ... normally the service is good, but this in an exception when the service was bad.   "Exceptionally bad service" ... very bad service, not merely bad but so bad it is beyond ordinary badness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why has Southern US English all but abandoned adverb forms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44943/why-has-southern-us-english-all-but-abandoned-adverb-forms) Flat adverbs (and modifiers-of-adjectives for those of us who dislike the traditional dustbinning) including this example: "Old John of Gaunt is grievous sick, my lord" — King Richard II, Act I, Sc. IV.

Comment: It sounds like a mistake to me. I've not heard it in US parlance or my sampling of Brit TV.